# Is this piece identifiable? A plus-shaped pyramid?

Tags: part-identification

Some kind of 1x1 slope.. a plus-shaped pyramid? I'm not sure where to start searching for this piece.. thanks for any help!

[image: a plus-shaped pyramid?]

Comment: Are you sure it's one piece, and not two cheese slopes connected to something else? What context can you give us? Where did you see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly looks similar to an upside down [Rock 1 x 1 Crystal 4 Point](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11127#T=C) rendered at low resolution:

[image]

An equally possible solution is a [Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Studs on 4 Sides](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4733) with four [Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54200) (aka cheese) on the side studs.

A less probable option is a [Brick, Round 1 x 1 with Fins](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4588) with exaggerated fin thickness and without any roundness:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, zovits--thank you! Turns out this is from a game ULTRAKILL and is a 'rodent piece'

Comment: @BbJug If it is from a non-LEGO-related video game, then why did you ask here? And why did you assume that it's a LEGO piece? Or did you not know where it was from?

Comment: The image was posted in a discord server where someone commented it looked like a Lego piece. In the spirit of this stack exchange I thought I would have luck identifying it but could not do so. I'm still impressed with how close your answer was despite the impossibility of the question.